# How to find an ID in a div class with multiple values BS4 Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to find an ID in a div class which has multiple values using BS4 the HTML is

```
<div class="size ">
<a class="selectSize"
  id="25746"
  data-ean="884751585616"
  ata-test="170"
  data-test1=""
  data-test2="1061364-41"
  data-test3-original="41"
  data-test4-eu="41"
  data-test5-uk="7"
  data-test6-us="8"
  data-test-cm="26"
</div>
</div>
```

I want to find data-test5-uk, my current code is soup =

```
bs(size.text,"html.parser")
sizes = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"size"})
size = sizes[0]["data-test5-uk"]
```

size.text is from a get request to the site with the html, however it returns

```
    size = sizes[0]["data-test5-uk"]
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1011, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'data-test5-uk'
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: `soup.find('a', {'class': 'selectSize'}).get('data-test5-uk')`?

Comment: @bro-grammer thanks that works  but forgot to say there are multiple versions of <div class="size "> how would I be able to find data-test5-uk for all of them?

Comment: `[a.find('a', {'class': 'selectSize'}).get('data-test5-uk') for a in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'size'})`

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how I'm suppose to format that? @bro-grammer

Comment: Also just one other thing, if data-test5-uk was equal to lets say 7 how could I get the id for that class?

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation** and then the **solution**.

`.find_all('tag')` is used to find all instances of that tag and we can later loop through them.

`.find('tag')` is used to find the **ONLY** first instance.

We can either extract the content of the argument with `['arg']` or .`.get('arg')` it is the **SAME**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="size ">
<a class="selectSize"
  id="25746"
  data-ean="884751585616"
  ata-test="170"
  data-test1=""
  data-test2="1061364-41"
  data-test3-original="41"
  data-test4-eu="41"
  data-test5-uk="7"
  data-test6-us="8"
  data-test-cm="26"
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

one_div = soup.find('div', class_='size ')

print( one_div.find('a')['data-test5-uk'])
# your code didn't work because you weren't in the a tag
# we have found the tag that contains the tag .find('a')['data-test5-uk']

# for multiple divs
for each in soup.find_all('div', class_='size '):
    # we loop through each instance and do the same
    datauk = each.find('a')['data-test5-uk']
    print('data-test5-uk:', datauk)
```

**Output**:

> data-test5-uk: 7

*Additional*

Why did your `['arg']`? - You've tried to extract the `["data-test5-uk"]` of the div. `<div class="size ">` the div has no arguments like that except one `class="size "`

Comment: Oh just realised this does not print the ID if data-test5-uk is located in size class @Elvir Muslic

Comment: I did kinda mention that in the additional part :D. If the answer solves your issue please mark it as such and upvote (if you liked it).

Comment: I'm a bit confused how it was mentioned sorry if I'm being dumb

Comment: `Why did your ['arg']? - You've tried to extract the ["data-test5-uk"] of the div. <div class="size "> the div has no arguments like that except one class="size "` meaning, Extracting from the >div< is not the same as extracting the attributes of the `<a ...>` tag. 
It's fine :D. These things as simple as they are, take time to get but once you do you'll be fine.  Summary: `['arg']` is used to extract attribute value but we have to do it on that exact tag. It's like asking if you're home at a random home. (won't find you (i.e. attribute) at that home.)